# RMagicK image.display does not return immediately

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, rmagick

I am using RMagicK for Ruby to draw and display images.  The problem is that after:

```
img = rvg.draw()
img.diaplay
```

control is not returned to the caller immediately.  The user has to manually close the window for the program to continue.  How can I bypass this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a sub-process that takes care of displaying the image for you, while you do some processing in the main process.

```
img = rvg.draw()
pid = fork { img.diaplay }

Process.detach(pid) # wait for the child in another thread.

# more code
```

Note that, fork is not available in some platforms, like Windows. You might have to use spawn if that's a problem for you.

Comment: Thanks, it works but when I wait 1 second and then try to kill it with `Process.kill("QUIT", pid)` it does not terminate.

Comment: @YanKingYin Now It gets trickier. If I remember well, `img.display` will use the underlining window system to display the image,  `X11` on Linux or `XQuartz` on Mac. So, the window system might be trapping the `SIGQUIT` signal. One possible solution would be sending a signal that can't be caught, like `SIGKILL` or `SIGSTOP`. Also, you can use `Timeout#timeout` in conjunction with  `Kernel#exit` to to stop the child process after a fix amount of seconds.

Comment: Thanks a lot, `SIGKILL` does it :)